# Bring in HTML from a separate file

Tags: jquery, html

I have a site that changes the content of the page when you hover over the navigation links: http://www.dolphinbeams.com/

Basically all the DIVs are on one page and I use jQuery to display them as necessary. However, to ensure compatibility with non-Javascript browsers, I have also created separate html files for each of the pages.

Each page has the same body content, with a different body id and title. I'm wondering if there's an easy way I can have the body content in a separate file (for editing), then bring it in to all the pages. What the simplest way to achieve this?

Keep in mind I don't know much about PHP, though I'd consider it if it's the easiest way. Also I'd like to ensure the content is still visible in case Javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename your index from html to .php.

add this line where you want your page to display:

```
    <? include("contentFile.html"); ?>
```

No other php knowledge required.

For example you have the divs that appear and disappear. It might look like this:

```
   <div id="content1"> 
           <? include("content1.html"); ?>
   </div>

   <div id="content2"> 
           <? include("content2.html"); ?>
   </div>
  ...
```

Comment: Wow that was easy. Thank you!